# SNMP Appender for logback

Tags: logback

How to create SNMP Appender for logback? There is a doc in logback manual for migrating log4j appender to logback but which doesn't seem to be working for converting log4j SNMPTrapAppender. Has anyone created logback version o SNMP appender?

Comment: What is not working about it? Do you see its methods being called? start() and append() ? Or is it being called, but not doing what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately, there is no SNMP appender for the moment.**

The best ***alternative solution*** is to ***write your own appender***. This can be done ***quite easily***.

*"You can easily write your appender by subclassing AppenderBase. It handles support for filters, status messages and other functionality shared by most appenders. The derived class only needs to implement one method, namely append(Object eventObject)."*

[Write your own Appender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have recently created a new logback snmp appender. Please have a look at https://github.com/anilkd/logback-snmp/wiki/logback-SNMP-appender